# How do I correctly use the OpenWriteAsync method to POST a file to an URL?

Tags: vb.net, post, upload, stream, webclient

I have been using the `UploadFileAsync` method to complete a file upload to remote server until it encounters a file above around 1gb where the RAM will spike to this filesize and crash the application.

A little research has to lead me to the OpenWriteAsync function to write as a filestream instead of attempting to read the whole file at once however I can't for the life of me find a VB.NET example I can get working, I've tried to convert from C# and use what I've found and here's what I have:

```
Private Shared Function InlineAssignHelper(Of T)(ByRef target As T, ByVal 
value As T) As T
        target = value
        Return value
    End Function
    Private Sub PushData(ByVal input As Stream, ByVal output As Stream)
        Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(4095) {}
        Dim bytesRead As Integer

    While (InlineAssignHelper(bytesRead, input.Read(buffer, 0, 
buffer.Length))) <> 0
        output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
    End While
End Sub
Private Sub UploadFile(ByVal fileName As String, ByVal data As Stream)
    Dim ub As New UriBuilder("http://someurl.com/uploader")

    Dim c As New WebClient
    AddHandler c.OpenWriteCompleted, AddressOf 
MyOpenWriteCompletedEventHandler
    c.OpenWriteAsync(ub.Uri)
End Sub

Public Sub MyOpenWriteCompletedEventHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal 
e As OpenWriteCompletedEventArgs)
    PushData(Data, e.Result)
    e.Result.Close()
    Data.Close()
End Sub
```

On the OpenWriteComplete event handler, what variable do I pass as **Data**?

Also which handler does the `openwriteasync` function require to monitor the current progress, does this method also trigger UploadProgressChanged event in the webclient object?

Thanks for your time.

EDIT:

```
private void UploadFiles(MyFileInfo mfi, System.IO.FileStream data)
{
UriBuilder ub = new 
UriBuilder("http://localhost:3793/receiver.ashx");
ub.Query = string.Format("filename={0}&name={1}&address={2}&email= 
{3}&golfid={4}", mfi.Name, fixText(txtName.Text), fixText(txtAdress.Text), 
fixText(txtEmail.Text), fixText(txtGolfID.Text));
//ub.Query = string.Format("filename={0}", mfi.Name);
WebClient wc = new WebClient();

wc.OpenWriteCompleted += (sender, e) =>
        {
            PushData(data, e.Result, mfi);
            e.Result.Close();
            data.Close();
            lbl.Text = "Fil(er) uppladdade!";
        };
        wc.OpenWriteAsync(ub.Uri);
    }
```

Here was the original C# code for the part I tried to convert - I have looked all over for a working VB.NET example it really seems one doesn't exist!

Private Shared Function InlineAssignHelper(Of T)(ByRef target As T, ByVal value As T) As T
        target = value
        Return value
    End Function
    Private Sub PushData(ByVal input As Stream, ByVal output As Stream)
        Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(4095) {}
        Dim bytesRead As Integer

```
    While (InlineAssignHelper(bytesRead, input.Read(buffer, 0, 
buffer.Length))) <> 0
        AddLog("Writing..")
        output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
    End While
End Sub

Private Sub UploadFileStream(uploadURL As String)
    Dim ub As New UriBuilder(uploadURL)
    AddLog("Uploading to: " & uploadURL)
    ub.Query = String.Format("file1={0}", "D:\test.flv")
    Dim c As New WebClient
    AddHandler c.OpenWriteCompleted, AddressOf OpenWriteCallback
    'AddHandler c.UploadProgressChanged, AddressOf OpenWriteProgress

    c.OpenWriteAsync(ub.Uri)


End Sub

Public Sub OpenWriteCallback(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As 
OpenWriteCompletedEventArgs)

    Dim fs As FileStream = File.OpenRead("D:\test.flv")
    AddLog("cb")
    PushData(fs, e.Result)

    If fs Is Nothing Then
            fs.Close()
        AddLog("done")
        MsgBox(e.Result)
    End If


End Sub
```

Given your comments I have come up with this however, it seems to say it's writing but when looking at outgoing traffic there is no upload going on or any response from the server, until it stops or crashes with a memory error, any ideas why this doesn't work?

Thank you

Comment: What did the C# example pass as the first argument to `PushData`?

Comment: You should do something wiith that `fileName`. You're never adding it to the [Uri.Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.query) (`ub.Query = "filename=" & fileName`) or using it in any way. `Data` is the input Stream. You could use `File.OpenRead()` to open the Stream, which you **must** close after.

Comment: Where is the code that calls `UploadFile()`? This method, as you have written it (pretty standard. btw), accepts a `Stream` argument. Well, that Stream is of course the `input` Stream that you pass to `PushData()`. The `output` stream is the `e.Result` value of the `OpenWriteCompleted` event `OpenWriteCompletedEventArgs`

Comment: I have tried to follow your instructions best I could here's what I come up with do you know why it isn't working still?